# How to change a div content

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a football website where there will be a navigation pane on the left. When you click on one of the tabs, it will bring up the corresponding video, hopefully through javascript. I want this to be done in the same html file, so it doesn't have to reload.

Here is the code for the navigation bar:

```
    <div class="highlights"><a><p>MATCH HIGHLIGHTS</p></a> </div>

        <a href="#"><div class="win">
            <div class="match"><p>Cardiff</p></div>
            <div class="score"><p>1-2</p></div>   
        </div></a> 
        <a href="#"><div class="loss">
            <div class="match"><p>Everton</p></div>
            <div class="score"><p>3-2</p></div>   
        </div></a> 
        <a href="#"><div class="win">
            <div class="match"><p>Leeds</p></div>
            <div class="score"><p>2-0</p></div>   
        </div></a> 
        <a href="#"><div class="loss">
            <div class="match"><p>Hull</p></div>
            <div class="score"><p>2-3</p></div>   
        </div></a>
```

and then the content will go inside this div:

```
<div id="content">      content goes here        </div>
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make function onclick on each hyperlink like this :

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="showGoals(1);"><div class="win">
            <div class="match"><p>Cardiff</p></div>
            <div class="score"><p>1-2</p></div>   
        </div></a> 


function showGoals(matchId) {
$.ajax({
success : fumction (data) {
$('#content').val(data);
}
});
return false;
}
```

Comment: Thats it! my main struggle was linking the javascript with the html, now I can mess about with it! Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read up on jQuery. Here's a good reference to change the HTML content, allowing you to add bold, emphasis, etc. [jQuery's `.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/). You may also want to `.text` works.